# 1004 run-time error as Excel cannot find the file

Tags: excel, vba

I use a virtual pc to run my macros.

Currently when I remote into this pc I find Excel open with a run-time error 1004 describing `File "Daily_Summary.xlsx" cannot be found` and when I open the `VBA` editor it has the following line highlighted:

```
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\PDFfiles\Daily_Summary.xlsx"
```

At this point `Daily_Summary.xlsx` does not exist, until it has been saved so I wouldn't expect the program to be able to find the file - therefore the error message seems strange.

Initially I thought maybe it would be network issues due to it being a virtual pc but the line of code is trying to save the file locally to the `c-drive` so how can it be a network issue?

Anybody ever experienced anything like this before?

Comment: Does folder `PDFfiles` exist? Also are you attempting to save a workbook containing code with .xlsx? It should be .xlsm

Comment: I assume that "Daily_Summary.xlsx" is a file different than the one from which the macro is run, isn't it? and thus "Excel" is an "Excel Application" Type variable referring to this other file. Is this the case?

Comment: What's the rest of your code?

Comment: @enderland "Rest of your code" - it is part of a VBA project spread over 4 modules and a class module - do you want the rest of that routine?

Comment: @ooo folder `C:\PDFfiles` definitely exists. The template is free of code and an xlsx file. + the error message would be different if I tried to save coded file as xlsx.

Comment: @varocarbas correct -  "Daily_Summary.xlsx" is a different file from the control xlsm file. Excel is _not_ a variable it is one of the upper most objects in the excel object model.

Comment: Then, my answer (the second paragraph) is fully applicable: you are intending to save the current workbook (containing macros by definition) to a non-macro-supporting format. Change this line to Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\PDFfiles\Daily_Summary.xlsm" and would work fine. If you want to generate a xlsx file, you would have to open it and copy there the contents you want.

Comment: @varocarbas this definitely is not the case. I use this model in many routines - A file `Control.xlsm` with all the `VBA` and a template - either `Template.xlsx` or `Daily_Summary.xlsx`. The control file then opens the template makes some changes to it and then saves a copy of it somewhere else - _template never has any code in it_

Comment: Don't get me wrong: you can open a xlsx file without any problem and save it as xlsx file. The reason why you might get this error is because you are saving the main macro. You are relying on the quite imprecise ActiveWorkbook: perhaps you forgot to select the given xlsx file, and the main xlsm is the active one; what is provoking the problem. The best way to make sure is not relying on ActiveWorkBook when dealing with multiple workbooks, but in the given workbook objects.

Comment: ok - now we're getting somewhere - I agree that maybe `Activeworkbook` is the problem - I usually try to avoid using it in production code. I'll add the target book to an object variable and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine in case of referring to a file different than the current one (from which the macro is executed). You would get a (1004) error message only if this file is not accessible for some reason.

On the other hand, if you are intending to save the current file (from which the macro is being executed), an error would be triggered every time because of intending to save it as a XLSX file. A file containing macros has to be stored as a macro-supporting format (e.g., XLSM). If you try to save it by relying on a wrong file type (like XLSX), you would get a prompt explaining the problem. But, if `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is present in your code, you would get the standard 1004 error message when the file cannot be accessed (as in the example above).

Comment: ok +1 for the help - the preceding line of code is indeed `Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` - I'll try commenting out that line for future runs of this routine and see what happens.

Comment: @whytheq Thanks. as suggested via comment. You have two options: saving the file as xlsm; or creating a new xlsx file and copy the contents you wish there. But you cannot save ActiveWorkbook as xlsx directly.

Comment: ....follow up question that (embarrassingly) I should already know...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428762/copying-a-worksheet-into-a-workbook-object-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428762/copying-a-worksheet-into-a-workbook-object-variable)

Comment: @whytheq the answers there seem to be pretty good already. You have one correction of your approach, a different approach... I cannot add anything worthy.

Comment: thanks varocarbas - this humble question&answer (and follow up question) has really opened a small can of worms in my mind (excuse the strange image) ... a small leap forward in my VBA will follow; thanks again.

Comment: @whytheq no problem, it is pretty descriptive. This is what this site is about: helping you to grow on all the sense, even in parts which you thought were completely under control (here, in the VBA-tagged questions, I have already got quite a few learned lessons in a pretty short time): KEEP GROWING AND LET THE WORMS SQUIRM FREE! (or well... replace them with a nicer animal :))