# Why does Worksheet.Copy not return a reference to the new workbook created

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code where `wb` is an existing multi-worksheet workbook. If I copy one of the sheets "Overview" a new workbook is created - so why does the following error saying "object required"?:

```
Dim wbCopy As Excel.Workbook
Set wbCopy = wb.Sheets("Overview").Copy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Worksheet.Copy` method doesn't return a reference to the new Workbook. You might use a Worksheet reference instead:

```
Dim wsCopy As Excel.Worksheet    'changed from wb to wsCopy
```

As you know, if you don't supply either the After or Before argument it copies to a new Workbook. Copying within the same workbook would use this code:

```
Set wsCopy = wb.Worksheets("Overview")
wsCopy.Copy After:= wb.Worksheets(1)    'or Before:=
```

If you want to copy the sheet to a new workbook, and retain a reference to it, then this needs to be done in stages:

```
Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsCopied As Excel.Worksheet

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
wsCopy.Copy before:=wbNew.Worksheets(1)
Set wsCopied = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
```

If you only need to keep a reference to the new workbook then just omit the last line (and the variable declaration for wsCopied).

Comment: I think the OP wants a new workbook.  The problem is returning a reference to that new workbook.

Comment: @chrisneilsen This did occur to me but it wasn't entirely clear from the OP. I've added to my answer a way to do this.

Comment: Worksheet.Copy does not return a reference to the new workbook because you cannot do `Set wbRef = wb.Sheets("Overview").Copy`. chris is simply taking advantage of the fact that the new workbook immediately becomes active.

Comment: This is what I thought since the start. But then I did some tests with .Select and .Copy and the results were different. Now I did redo the tests and both situations deliver identical results (a bit tired today :)). Yes, you are right, sorry. Will delete my comments.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the few occasions you have to use one of the `Active*` objects

```
wb.Sheets("Overview").Copy
Set wbCopy = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: hmmm - +1 but I'm definitely trying to avoid Active* as later code starts to get confused. I'll try @AndyG approach

Comment: You only need ActiveWorkbook immediately after the copy.  From then on use your variable.

Answer (score 3):

The worksheets copy method appears to return a boolean value rather than a workbook object. To set a reference to the workbook you can use the following.

```
Sub wbcopy()

Dim wbcopy As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbIndex As Excel.Workbook
Dim sArray() As String
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim bfound As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

ReDim sArray(Workbooks.Count)

'Find the names of all the current workbooks
For Each wbIndex In Workbooks
    sArray(iIndex) = wbIndex.FullName
Next wbIndex

'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
wb.Sheets("Overview").Copy

'Find the sheet with the new name
For Each wbIndex In Workbooks

    bfound = False

    For iIndex = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
        If wbIndex.FullName = sArray(iIndex) Then
            bfound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next iIndex

    If Not bfound Then
        Set wbcopy = wbIndex
        Exit For
    End If

Next wbIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 that's good - I believe the answer by @AndyG is more compact and more direct - but I still like this. Thanks.

Comment: This solution just needs to increment the iIndex counter in the first loop which is storing workbook names. Right now it keeps overwriting the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing today. To me the active* objects is too vague so I looked for a way to reliably determine the sheet object.
Just if anyone's looking for this, here's for the files:

```
dim sws, tws as worksheet

set sws = thisworkbook.sheets("source")
sws.copy before:=sws
set tws = sws.previous
```

That does the job

rn43x

Comment: I like this approach.  Beware of hidden worksheets however: if you copy a hidden worksheet, both it and the copy will be hidden and this code will fail (since `worksheet.previous` only returns visible worksheets).  You can test for this though.