# Object Required Error in excel VBA while trying to rename the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a particular sheet and rename it to final. the code is as follows :

```
Sub CreateSheet()
  Worksheets("Key metrics").Copy(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Final"
End Sub
```

The program executes till copying the sheet with the contents but then it throws the error and doesn't rename my new sheet to final.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in connection with the nesting that you're carrying out. `Copy` does not return a sheet object, hence your error.

Try this:

```
Sub CreateSheet()
  with Excel.thisworkbook
    .Worksheets("Key metrics").Copy Before:=.Worksheets(1)
    .activesheet.Name = "Final"
  end with
End Sub
```

Here is a QA that confirms this:
[Why does Worksheet.Copy not return a reference to the new workbook created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428762/why-does-worksheet-copy-not-return-a-reference-to-the-new-workbook-created)

If this is going to be a small self-contained `helper` routine you could make it a function with a worksheet return type:

```
Sub tst()

Dim mySht As Excel.Worksheet
Set mySht = crtSheet("foobar", "barfoo") '<<used via this

End Sub

Function crtSheet(ByVal tgtSheet As String, ByVal newName As String) As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim s As Excel.Worksheet
  With Excel.ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets(tgtSheet).Copy Before:=.Worksheets(1)
    Set s = .ActiveSheet
    s.Name = newName
  End With
  Set crtSheet = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateSheet()
Dim WS As Worksheet

Worksheets("Key metrics").Copy Before:=Worksheets(1)
Set WS = ActiveSheet
WS.Name = "Final"

End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you do this?  `Set WS = ActiveSheet` ... `WS` does not get used

Comment: whytheq's answer is simpler and works. The problem in the OP's code is caused by the naming of the new sheet. The two WS lines in your code are redundant.

Comment: Just written in haste with from a habit of ensuring I am using the correct Sheet I guess. But your right, no need for it.

Comment: if you replace `ActiveSheet` with `WS` in the last line of your code then it gets used?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Edited.