# Store COPY of a worksheet in worksheet variable

Tags: vba, excel

### What I want to achieve:

I want to assign copy of a worksheet to variable, for later use.

### What I tried and results

**First :** The code below works fine. Something like this I would like to achieve, but using `worksheet.copy`.

```
Sub DuplicateSheetRenameFirst()
    Dim wsDuplicate As Worksheet
    Set wsDuplicate = Worksheets.Add
    wsDuplicate.Name = "Duplicate"
End Sub
```

---

**Second :** Using the copy method, creates a worksheet in current workbook, but generates a **Runtime error 424 - Object required**.

```
Sub DuplicateSheetRenameSecond()

    Dim wsDuplicate As Worksheet
    Set wsDuplicate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    'above line : runtime error 424 object required, but the sheet is created
    wsDuplicate.Name = "Duplicate"

End Sub
```

---

**Third :** Creates a worksheet in new workbook (so creates book, then sheet), but still generates the same **Runtime error 424 - Object required**.

```
Sub DuplicateSheetRenameThird()

    Dim wsDuplicate As Worksheet
    Set wsDuplicate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
    'above line : runtime error 424 object required, but the sheet is created in new workbook
    wsDuplicate.Name = "Duplicate"

End Sub
```

---

**Workaround :** I can modify any of the **second** or **third** way to at first copy the sheet and then set the variable to activesheet, but I was wandering if there is a one step way of doing this. I'm not sure if this would work all the time, since the activesheet may not be the one just copied, maybe.

---

### The Question:

Is there a simple (one step) way to store the copy of a worksheet in a variable? Preferably without errors or without filtering the error with error handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe ok?

```
Sub copySheet()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
Set ws = Excel.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

End Sub
```

It is unfortunate that in this case you need to use an `Active...` object. Generally it is good practice to avoid `Active...` objects.

You cannot do this though as the method `.copy` is not returning an object of the worksheet class:

```
Sub copySheet()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy(After:=Sheets(1))

End Sub
```

Some further explanation is in this previous post:
[Why does Worksheet.Copy not return a reference to the new workbook created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428762/why-does-worksheet-copy-not-return-a-reference-to-the-new-workbook-created)

In `MSDN` it is not altogether obvious that the method returns nothing:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837784.aspx

...but in your friend Excel's Object Explorer it is more obvious. If it returned a worksheet object then by the arrow would read:

> Sub Copy([Before], [After]) **as Worksheet**

[image]

Comment: The first code, I thought about it and was doing it that way (see the **Workaround** section of my question). The second code and explanation, that is what I've been looking for :). Thank you.

Comment: Great explanation. I've known this to be an issue, but I never went so far as to browse the object explorer. To avoid using the `Active...` reference, I generally control the worksheet with which I am working by using indices. For example: `Sheet1.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)` `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Hello"`

Comment: @user3561813 in this case, where we are not 100% sure of the index, name or number of the newly added sheet, I think `Activesheet` is the safest way of identifying it. In general though you are correct either use `Sheet1.` or `worksheets("sheet1").` or `worksheets("foobar").` or `sheets(1).` to avoid using `Activesheet.`

Comment: @whytheq Agreed. That's why we use the `Worksheets.Count` property to determine the number of sheets, then place the newly copied sheet after. Next we could assign the worksheet at the `.Count` index (which will be the new sheet, since we specified that it go to this index) to a variable.