# VBA to save workbook twice as different types in the same location

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have some code that seems to work great on PC's in the house but as soon as I try them in Work they don't seem to work. Really strange. Any ideas?

The idea of the script is to

1. ask for a name with a pop up
2. ask for a location to save
3. Then will move some things around.
4. then it will save the a workbook as an xlsm with the name given in step 1 in the location given in step.
5. then it will save the worksheet again as am xml with the name in step 1 given but added the text "-upload" to the file name to the location previously selected in step 2.

I know it seems strange but it works on some but not on others, any reason for this?
The error I get on some is

> Run-time error '1004':  The file could not be accessed. Try one of the
>   following:
>
> - Make the specified folder exist.
> - Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
> - Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  < > ? [ ] : | or *
> - Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

Any help is welcomed. The code I have is

```
Sub save_as_xlsm_and_XML()
Dim filename
Dim XML_Name_Complete
Dim XLSM_Name
Dim Temp_Name
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim Last_Column As Long

filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Temp_Name = InputBox("Enw Dosbarth")
If Temp_Name = "" Then Exit Sub



Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

XLSM_Name = sItem & "\" & Temp_Name
XML_Name_Complete = sItem & "\" & Temp_Name & "-lanlwythiad"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' turn off the screen updating

'Moving data from final_before_copy to adroddiad
    Sheets("Final_Before_Copy").Select
    Rows("8:250").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
    Sheets("adroddiad").Select
    Rows("8:8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("1:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True

' Arbed fel XML '

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Range("a1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Adroddiad"
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

ChDir sItem

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=XML_Name_Complete _
, FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet, CreateBackup:=True
If XML_Name_Complete = False Then Exit Sub
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True


'Arbed fel xlsm'
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Marciau").Select
Range("A6").Select

ChDir sItem
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=XLSM_Name _
, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",False)"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' turn on the screen updating

successful_export = MsgBox("Adroddiad wedi ei arbed ac allforio yn lwyddiannus", , "System Adroddiadau")

NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [This response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18419340/3657636) may address your issue.

Comment: `Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.` Have you verified this if it is not working? Maybe the path `sItem` is to long?